# Why my baked texture (normal, not combined), like a camo dalmata?

Tags: texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I was following this Blender Guru tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw&t=304s but in the middle of the process the things just gone wrong.

I don't know what happend, i did everything just like Andrew Price explained it but in my Anvil texture has these black spots:
[image]

What am i doing wrong? i followed everything showed in the video but this is the result. 
(BTW, i don't have the principled bsdf, so i'm trying to make tried to make it look like metal, if there's something wrong with the node edition, let me know it too, please ^^)

Comment: have you tried to connect the "normal map" output to "normal" in the "glossy shader"? Maybe you can share the blend file, so we can test and see...

Comment: Is it possible that you are seeing the 2 objects at the same time (since they are overlapped). Please try to move one object to a different layer, or turn off the visibility.

Comment: I did everything just like in the video, and no, i don't have any overlapping object so... that's it. I'll try what you told me to do at first.